# How to validate email&password using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

how to validate login email & password using redux? a already make a handleLogin function it work fine when user input the right email&password but if user submit the wrong email&password the api crash

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  try {
    const masuk = login(dispacth, { email, password })
    // history.push("/")
  } catch (error) {
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'top-end',
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'Email atau Password tidak sesuai',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500,
    })
  }
}
```

and my dispatch

```js
export const login = async (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch(loginStart())
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(BASE_URL + 'auth/login', user)
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(loginFailure(error))
  }
}
```

Comment: _"if user submit the wrong email&password the api crash"_ - and what does that have to do with the code you've posted?

Comment: It means that `Swal.fire` is called.

Comment: Redux is a state management library, it has nothing at all to do with validating user input. Your code should validate the data ***prior to*** dispatching the action to the store to effect an asynchronous action. If you want to validate the data in the action then again this should be done ***prior to*** attempting to call the backend API. If  you are using Redux Toolkit why are you not creating asynchronous actions, e.g. `createAsyncThunk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run validation before the submission of the form, here is how you would do it:

```js
function isValidEmail(email: string): boolean {
  const regex =
    /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  return regex.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

function isPasswordValid(password: string): boolean {
  /*
   * At least one lowercase letter ((?=.*[a-z])).
   * At least one uppercase letter ((?=.*[A-Z])).
   * At least one digit ((?=.*\d)).
   * Consists of only alphanumeric characters ([a-zA-Z\d]).
   * Has a minimum length of 8 characters ({8,}).
   */
  const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$/;

  return regex.test(password);
}

const handleClick = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ((!email || !isValidEmail(email)) && (!password || !isPasswordValid(password))) {
    Swal.fire({
      position: "top-end",
      icon: "error",
      title: "Email or Password are invalid",
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });

    return;
  }
  try {
    const masuk = await login(dispacth, { email, password });
    // history.push("/")
  } catch (error) {
    Swal.fire({
      position: "top-end",
      icon: "error",
      title: "Email atau Password tidak sesuai",
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });
  }
};
```

but I recommend you to check out [React Hook Form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/get-started/) which handles everything you think of related to forms and validations

Example with react hook form:

make sure you have react-hook-form and yup installed in your project:

```bash
npm install react-hook-form @hookform/resolvers yup
```

```js
import {yupResolver} from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";

const LoginForm = () => {

    const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
        email: yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Email is required'),
        password: yup.string().required('Password is required').min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters'),
    });

    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema), // Using yup validation schema
    });


    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data); // Handle form submission here
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input {...register("email")}/>
                {errors.email && <p role="alert">{errors.email.message}</p>}
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" {...register("password")}/>
                {errors.password && <p role="alert">{errors.password.message}</p>}
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an async function without using `await` so the promise is not handled properly.

Try:

```js
const masuk = await login(dispacth, { email, password })
```

Comment: Isn't the issue here that the form is submitted before running validations on the email/password and also the promise is not handled properly?

Comment: Validating email for formatting/presence is a nice thing to do on frontend but you'd still definitely want to do it on backend. I am assuming that the issue here refers more to "incorrect email/password".